# Stopping the Cylons from getting Hera

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In season 3 episode 3 (Exodus, Part 1) Laura Roslin stresses how important it is that Hera not fall into the hands of the Cylons. She says,

> "... it is imperative that [Maya] and [Hera] get off this planet ...".

If that is true, then **why not put Maya and Hera, or even other "high value targets", on a Raptor and send them safely to Galactica before the Exodus?** Two Raptors landed on New Caprica, during the occupation, to help the resistance prepare for Galactica's return. And later Helo states that a Raptor just jumped back.

However, that raptor could be the one that orbits New Caprica in order to communicate with the resistance; not one that was on New Caprica. But I don't see why one of the Raptors on New Caprica couldn't jump back.

Comment: humans (including show writers) are not perfect...